# MySQL 1040 (HY000): Too many connections

Tags: mysql

To start, I'm familiar with the MySQL error, but it's an unexplainable situation which we want to understand.

To start, we have the setting:

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| max_connections        | 151   |
| mysqlx_max_connections | 100   |
+------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

So far so good. However, we are currently running into: `ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections` during connecting to the database.

So, we thought we had 150 connections open (and 1 preserved for the root-user).

That wasn't the case as:

```
Threads_connected 15
Threads_running 11
```

So, this seems to be some other kind of situation? We've read about the number of connections since the start of the MySQL instance. This number seems quite high, since we are seeing this value:

```
Aborted_clients 1063649
Aborted_connects 41
```

However, we are not completely sure if this is the issue? Clearly, the error is not raised because of the number of concurrent connections, as that where only 11 connections...

Does anybody have an idea or a direction to point us to?

For now, we've solved the issue by issuing: `mysqladmin flush-hosts` but we want to understand (and eventually prevent) this situation

Comment: Check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';` That will tell you the high-water mark that `Threads_connected` reached at some time in the past (though it is reset if you restart mysqld).

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for your reply. Currently that's set to 49 (but we've restarted the server eventually). So this would have read 150 you guess?

Comment: It's not a counter. Clearly it shows something higher than the `Threads_connected` value of 15, even though you have restarted the server. Threads connected is only what it is at the moment you run that command. But the number of clients connected rises and falls as your applications make database connections. So it's not unusual for it to rise to the max briefly, and then you get the error. The fixes are either to increase `max_connections` to allow for the expected spikes in traffic, or else to throttle your application so it reduces the demand on the database.

Comment: Flush hosts has nothing to do with the number of clients connected.

Comment: @BillKarwin alright but that's strange though. `flush-hosts` made us able to connect to the database again. I think this value was indeed higher, but the strange thing is that there are only Cronjobs running that connect to the database. This is running for like 60 days without issues and than all of a sudden we get this issue. So we think it's related to something else causing/triggering this error. But we've no idea how to look into this. I will keep an eye on the `max_used_connections` to see if it slowly increases over time

Comment: @BillKarwin what I also don't understand. Perhaps the `max_used_connetions` spiked above 150 for short period of time, but the connections at the time when we tried to connect (and got the errors) was clearly below 150 (under 20 actually). So, why is MySQL still refusing all new connections? Will it keep refusing until the `max_used_connections` is rested? Perhaps `flush-hosts` resets this counter? I'm confused why MySQL kept refusing new connections while the active connections at that time was quite low

Comment: Suppose three clients connects, and then two disconnect. `max_used_connections` will be three, because it records the highest number of threads connected at any one time. But you see only one connected when you view the `Threads_connected` status! What's confusing about this?

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, I understand that. But, MySQL keeps refusing new connections while `max_used_connections` is still high, but `Threads_connected` is low, for instance only 20. So that's what confuses me. Shouldn't MySQL allow new connections again when the actual `Threads_connected` get's lowered (because we are shutting down services that kill their database connections to open up connections lots)

Comment: Clients can connect very briefly, and the threads connected can increase suddenly, between the times you view the status variables.

Comment: @BillKarwin Alright, I can agree with that. I will have to check the `Max_used_connections_time` variable next time it happens to verify this. Do you agree?

Comment: Sure, if you could correlate that time with the first time your application got the error about too many connections, it would help to prove that. You may also get the error on subsequent times, but without the max_used_connections updating. It can't go above max_connections+1, so the high-water mark won't change.

Comment: This looks like a question that should have been asked on [dba.se]. Take a look at [these questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=MySQL+too+many+connections)

Answer (score 0):

Summary of comment thread above:

- Status variables `Threads_connected` and `Max_used_connections` are not counters. `Threads_connected` is a gauge indicating how many clients are connected at the moment you view the status variables. `Max_used_connections` is the high-water mark of `Threads_connected` at any time since the server started.
- Clients may connect briefly, driving up the `Threads_connected` until it hits the limit defined by `Max_connections`. That's when further connection attempts get an error, until some clients disconnect.
- Clients may disconnect quickly, so if you use `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` you don't see the peak `Threads_connected`. You would have to run that at exactly the right instant to see the high threads connected. Nevertheless, the fact that your application got errors indicates that at some moment, there were too many clients connected.
- You can increase `Max_connections` if you need to support a greater maximum number of client connections. The default of 150 is very low for many production applications. On a properly sized server, MySQL can support hundreds or thousands of threads connected (as long as most of them are idle).
- Flush hosts has nothing to do with the the number of clients connected. If the errors stopped after you ran flush hosts, it was a coincidence.